# How does this capacitor discharge?

Tags: capacitor, schematics

I have this schematics here
[image]

Does anyone know how the capacitor in the black circle (disregard the blue circles) can discharge once it is charged up and the power has been disconnected.

It is suggested that it is discharged through the resistor but this cant be because once it is charged its left plate will be +5Vcc and the right plate 0V so to discharge through the resistor the charge would have to go through the insulation through the resistor and to ground?? Witch is impossible unless the capacitor is bad.

Comment: There is NO ideal capacitor. The real equivalent is with a resistor (high value) in parallel with capacitance, which is the insulator between plates resistance. So there is leakage current all the time.  Typically in in electrolytic capcitors the leakage current is around 5~15μA per μF, which is really high!

Comment: Thinking and questioning are both extremely good ideas - they will take you far. BUT do also listen to what people say and work through stuff you do not understand. If in doubt ask. Ambiorix's "-5V" explanation is essentially correct but you tend to reject it as unlikely, without having any reason to do so than intuition. In this case intuition fails. The voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantaneously nor if no current flows. At power-off there is +5V across the cap. When V+ falls to 0V there is still 5V across the cap so the bottom must be at -5V. In practice things like IC body ...

Comment: ... diodes and other muddy the waters but that shos the basic principle.

Comment: i did not reject -5v explanation, look below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will discharge when the +Vcc is switched off. The left plate is then connected to the ground via the power supply. The RST input then becomes -Vcc with respect to the ground and discharges via the resistor. 
+Vcc present:

[image]

+Vcc not present:

[image]

When the capacitor is charged the left plate is +5V with respect to the right plate. Since the +5Vcc power supply is connected to the left plate of the capacitor with the opposite polarity, the RST pin is +5v-(+5V) = 0V. However when you cut the power supply the left plate is connected to the GND (0V). RST then becomes 0V - (+5V) = -5V.

Comment: Why would the RST pin become -Vcc when it is 0V after capacitor charge up?

Comment: And take the simplest Voltage regulator possible a resistor in series with a Zener diode, if the input is cut of then the capacitor on the output would still reverse bias the Zener diode and would discharge down to the breakdown voltage of the diode but not fully.

Comment: Even if the PS has no leakage resistance at all, the other components in the circuit do.

Comment: Ok, I think I made some sense of it, when the power is cut of and if the capacitor is then connected via power supply to ground then the left plate will loose charge while the right plate will pull charge from the ground through the resistor, right ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: When a PS it is not working, then the output it is connected to ground (0Ω) or it is very high? In this case if you connect again the input, the PS will see a short in the out?

Comment: That depends on the total parallel leakage resistance of the PS plus rest of the circuit. Is generally not 0Ω, but even if leakage is 100KΩ (very high) the capacitor is completely discharged after 5RC = 5x10μFx(100kΩ  + 10kΩ) = 5.5sec. This is one reason why some devices need to be switched off for a few seconds to reset properly.

Comment: @ Ambiorix And what if (+) wire of PS disconnected or there is a diode in series to the PS?